# No option for C++ project in Qt Creator (QtSDK Community Installation)

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have installed (and reinstalled) the QtSDK Community version on Windows 7 64-bit.  When I launch Qt Creator there is no option for C++ Project.  Others have solved this problem by making sure qmake.exe is properly detected under Tools-->Options-->Build & Run-->Qt Versions but it appears to be in my installation:

[image]

Comment: What C++ compiler(s) do you have installed?

Comment: The first installation auto-detected an existing MS Visual C++ compiler. Before reinstalling the SDK I also installed MinGW, which was not autodetected, and added gcc to QT Creator manually.

Answer (score 0):

First go to File->New and check the drop-down box in the top right: Is it set to show the relevant templates ("All templates" is the save bet).

If it does: Please check the Kits tab in Tools>Options>Build & Run: Is there a kit using the desktop device type with a compiler and Qt version? Do compiler and Qt version match (same type and version)?

With the Qt in the screenshot you need to have MSVC 2013 set up and detected. MSVC 2010 or any other version does *not* work, nor does mingw since the binaries that result from building with one compiler and linking to a Qt built with a different compiler does tend to crash more or less randomly.

Once you have a Kit with a Qt version the additional wizards should become available.

Comment: All templates are being shown. The compiler and version listed under Kits is the same but there is a "warning" icon (a yellow triangle with an exclamation mark in it). I would be happy to switch from MSVC to  GCC.

Comment: The warning appears to be that there is no debugger. Manually adding GDB doesn't clear it though.